# Execution of php file with commande

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony 2.8 for my project. this is the code of php file that i would to execute with commande:

```
 use Video\IntelligenceBundle\Entity\Entry;
 use Video\IntelligenceBundle\Entity\Visits;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;


 class ConvertVisitsIncomeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
 {
public function configure()
{
    $this->setName('app:convert-visits')
        ->setDescription('Convertir les entrée de la table visits a la 
table entry')
    ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface 
$output)
{

    /** @var EntityManager $em */

    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

   // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $output->writeln("sss"); 
    /** @var Video\IntelligenceBundle\Entity\Visits $visit */
    $visitsRepository = $em->getRepository(Visits::class);

    $visits = $visitsRepository->findAll();
    $groupedVisitsByPerson = [];

    /** @var Video\IntelligenceBundle\Entity\Visits $visit */
    foreach ($visits as $visit)
        $groupedVisitsByPerson[$visit->getIdPerson()][] = $visit;

    $visitDate = null;
    $leaveDate = null;
    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($groupedVisitsByPerson as $personId => $visits) {
        try {

            $i      = 0;
            $length = count($visits);
            $visitDate = null;
            $leaveDate = null;
            /** @var \AppBundle\Entity\Visits $visit */
            foreach ($visits as $visit) {
                $i++;
                if($visit->getVisitDate()->getTimestamp() <= 0) {
                    $em->remove($visit);
                    continue;
                }
                if(is_null($visitDate)) {
                    $visitDate = $visit->getVisitDate();
                    $tmp[] = $visit;
                    if($length == $i) {
                        $entry = new Entry();
                        $entry
                            ->setVisitDate($visitDate)
                            ->setLeaveDate(null)
                            ->setIdPerson($personId)
                            ->setCamera($visit->getCamera());
                        $em->persist($entry);
                        $output->writeln("<success>".$entry->getIdPerson()." added</success>");
                    }
                } else {
                    $diff = $visit->getVisitDate()->diff($visitDate);
                    $seconds = $diff->s + $diff->i * 60 + $diff->h * 3600;
                    if($length == $i) {
                        $tmp[]     = $visit;
                        $leaveDate = $visit->getVisitDate();
                        if($leaveDate == $visitDate) {
                            $leaveDate = null;
                        }

                        $entry = new Entry();
                        $entry
                            ->setVisitDate($visitDate)
                            ->setLeaveDate($leaveDate)
                            ->setIdPerson($personId)
                            ->setCamera($visit->getCamera());
                        $em->persist($entry);
                        $output->writeln("<success>".$entry->getIdPerson()." added</success>");

                        $visitDate = null;
                        $leaveDate = null;
                    }
                    elseif($seconds > 0 && $seconds <= 60 ) {
                        $leaveDate = $visit->getVisitDate();
                        $tmp[]     = $visit;
                    }
                    elseif($seconds > 60) {
                        $entry = new Entry();
                        $entry
                            ->setVisitDate($visitDate)
                            ->setLeaveDate($leaveDate)
                            ->setIdPerson($personId)
                            ->setCamera($visit->getCamera());
                        $em->persist($entry);

                        $visitDate = $visit->getVisitDate();
                        $leaveDate = null;
                        $tmp[]     = $visit;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($tmp as $visit)
                $em->remove($visit);

            $em->flush();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln("<error>".$e->getMessage()." </error>");


        }

    }

 }
   }
```

when i try to execute this code with this commande :

`sudo php /opt/lampp/htdocs/vi-old/app/console app:convert-visits --env=prod`

I have this issue

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or
>   directory

who can help me to solve this problem please.

Comment: try calling your php file with suffix like `sudo php myPhpFile.php`

Comment: also it not work. i have this issue : sudo php /opt/lampp/htdocs/vi-old/src/Video/IntelligenceBundle/Command/ConvertVisitsIncomeCommand.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vi-old/src/Video/IntelligenceBundle/Command/ConvertVisitsIncomeCommand.php on line 15

Comment: Please do never run anything with `sudo` just to solve some random problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with MySQL itself. Ensure you have the socket configured and the file is present. Run `php -i | grep mysql.sock` and look for the `*.default_socket`.

You can reinstall a mysql extension as well.

Also, as mentioned above, it's a bad idea to run commands with `sudo`